# Is there a way to push from vscode to github under a different username?

Tags: git, github, version-control, reference, git-push

I recently change my username of GitHub, but the work that I am doing right now can't push to the old name because it is under my previous name. How can I fix it?

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:old-username/repo.git'
```

Is there a way to do `git push git@github.com:new-username/repo.git`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In command line, go to your repository folder and type:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:new-username/repo.git
```

Then open your VSCode again, and see if it does pick up the new URL.